# Prove the existence of conditional expectations in $\mathcal{L}^2$

Tags: probability-theory, hilbert-spaces, conditional-expectation

Let $X \in \mathcal{L}^2(\Omega,\mathcal{A},P)$ be a square integrable real random variable. Then for any sub-$\sigma$-algebra $ \mathcal{C}$ of $\mathcal{A}$ and any $ \mathcal{C}$ measurable $Y \in \mathcal{L}^2(\Omega,\mathcal{A},P)$ we have

$$E[(X-X_0)^2]\leq E[(X-Y)^2]$$

with equality holding if and only if $Y=X_0$ a.s.. Here $X_0$ is a version of the conditional expectation $E[X|\mathcal{C}]$.

The exercise asks to use this result to show the existence of $E[X|\mathcal{C}]$ for any $X \in \mathcal{L}^2(\Omega,\mathcal{A},P)$ using the theory of Hilbert spaces.

My argument is

Pass over to the quotient space $L_2:=\mathcal{L}^2(\Omega,\mathcal{A},P) / \mathcal{N}(\Omega,\mathcal{C},P_{\mathcal{C}}) $ where

$$\mathcal{N}(\Omega,\mathcal{C},P_{\mathcal{C}}):=\{X\in \mathcal{L}^2(\Omega,\mathcal{C},P_{\mathcal{C}}):X=0 \text{  }P_{\mathcal{C}}\text{-a.s.} \} \subset \mathcal{L}^2(\Omega,\mathcal{A},P) $$
and $P_{\mathcal{C}}$ denotes the restriction of $P$ to $\mathcal{C}$. This is a Hilbert space with respect to the norm induced by the following inner product:

$$\langle \tilde{X},\tilde{Y} \rangle \mapsto \int XYdP$$

where $X$,$Y \in \mathcal{L}^2(\Omega,\mathcal{A},P)$ are arbitrary representatives of the classes $\tilde{X}$,$\tilde{Y} \in L_2$ respectively.

Let $L^{\mathcal{C}}_2:=\mathcal{L}^2(\Omega,\mathcal{C},P_{\mathcal{C}}) / \mathcal{N}(\Omega,\mathcal{C},P_{\mathcal{C}})$. Since $\mathcal{L}^2(\Omega,\mathcal{C},P_{\mathcal{C}}) \subset \mathcal{L}^2(\Omega,\mathcal{A},P)$, every equivalent class of  $L^{\mathcal{C}}_2$ is an equivalent class of $L^2$, and so $L^{\mathcal{C}}_2$ is subspace of $L^2$.

Now, $L^{\mathcal{C}}_2$ is a Hilbert space in its own right. It is complete, and in particular closed. Hence given $X\in \mathcal{L}^2(\Omega,\mathcal{A},P)$ we can apply the projection theorem to an arbitrary $\tilde{X} \in L^2$ and obtain a unique vector $\tilde{X}_0 \in L^{\mathcal{C}}_2$ such that

$$ || \tilde{X} - \tilde{X}_0 || \leq || \tilde{X} - \tilde{Y} || $$

for all $\tilde{Y} \in L^{\mathcal{C}}_2$, with equality holding if and only if $\tilde{Y}=\tilde{X}_0$.

Translating back into expectations and using the result above we see that each $X_0 \in \tilde{X}_0$ is a version of $E[X|\mathcal{C}]$. Conversely if $Z_0$ is a version $E[X|\mathcal{C}]$, then we see that we must have $\tilde{Z}_0=\tilde{X}_0$.

Hence $\tilde{X}_0$ is precisely the class of all conditional expectation versions of $X$.

Am I missing something? My definition of $L^2$ is not the usual one, since I use $\mathcal{N}(\Omega,\mathcal{C},P_{\mathcal{C}})$ instead of $\mathcal{N}(\Omega,\mathcal{A},P)$. I feel like this is necessary.

Comment: This seems like a weird way to do it. The point is that $L^2(\Omega,\mathcal{C},P)$ is already a Hilbert subspace of $L^2(\Omega,\mathcal{A},P)$ so you can already project onto it.

Comment: @Ian I don't see why $L^2(\Omega,\mathcal{C},P)$ must be a subspace of $L^2(\Omega,\mathcal{A},P)$. I feel there some null sets issues here.

Comment: ...No, linear combinations of measurable and square integrable functions are measurable and square integrable, and measurability with respect to $\mathcal{C}$ gives measurability with respect to $\mathcal{A}$ a fortiori. Where you juggle some null set issues is when you aren't already quotienting out by a.s. equivalence in the first place, in which case neither of these spaces is actually Hilbert (since the inner product is not positive definite) and you have to do projection slightly differently (basically by splashing "a.s."'s all over the place).

Comment: @Ian I agree that $\mathcal{L}^2(\Omega,\mathcal{C},P)$ is a subspace of $\mathcal{L}^2(\Omega,\mathcal{A},P)$ , but is $L^2(\Omega,\mathcal{C},P)$ a subspace of $L^2(\Omega,\mathcal{A},P)$ ? These are quotient spaces.

Comment: If perchance it's not, it's only because they don't literally contain the same objects, so you just map them to $L^2$ of the completion. Or, with less fancy machinery, just identify an equivalence class in $L^2(\Omega,\mathcal{C},P)$ with an equivalence class in $L^2(\Omega,\mathcal{A},P)$ if they have an element in common, which will ultimately do the same thing.

Comment: @Ian I see, but the point of my adjustment is precisely to avoid completion. I think it is clear that every equivalent class of $L^2(\Omega,\mathcal{C},P)$ is contained in some equivalent class of  $L^2(\Omega,\mathcal{A},P)$, but the latter one might be strictly larger. By considering only $\mathcal{C}$ measurable null modifications I can avoid this problem.

Comment: @Ian I didn't follow you there. Can you explain what you mean by "quotienting by functions which are $0$ $P_C$ a.s. doesn't actually give you what you want"?

Comment: Sorry, I misremembered a detail. Anyway, you still have a technical problem in that $L_2$ is not Hilbert. It can be managed (indeed you can develop this whole theory without quotienting at all), but it's there.

Comment: @Ian I don't see why $L_2$ as defined is not a Hilbert space. It is an inner product space and it is complete because every Cauchy sequence in $\mathcal{L}^2(\Omega,\mathcal{A},P)$ converges in squared mean in $\mathcal{L}^2(\Omega,\mathcal{A},P)$.

Comment: Its inner product isn't positive definite unless $\mathcal{C}$ is complete.

Comment: @Ian Good point! So then the best solution would be to do as you said before: identify equivalent classes of   $L^2(\Omega,\mathcal{C},P)$ with the equivalent classes of  the (usual) $L^2(\Omega,\mathcal{A},P)$ containing them (this latter $L^2$ being a Hilbert space now!). With this identification $L^2(\Omega,\mathcal{C},P)$ is a subspace of $L^2(\Omega,\mathcal{A},P)$, and also a Hilbert subspace if am not mistaken. Right?

Comment: @Ian This is because the identification doesn't change the norm or the inner product of the equivalent classes.

Comment: That's right. The identification is a bona fide isomorphism of Hilbert spaces.

Comment: @Ian I tried to spell out the details below. I assume the rest of my argument was OK? Can you tell me if my answer is correct? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted by Ian, my definition of $L^2$ is problematic because the inner product $\langle \tilde{X},\tilde{Y} \rangle \mapsto \int XYdP$ is not positive definite. This is because if $X=0$ $P$-a.s. and $X$ is not $\mathcal{C}$ measurable, then $\tilde{X}\neq\tilde{0}$ but $\langle \tilde{X},\tilde{X} \rangle =0$.

We can alternatively proceed thus:

Define $$L_2:=\mathcal{L}^2(\Omega,\mathcal{A},P) / \mathcal{N}(\Omega,\mathcal{A},P)$$

$$L^{\mathcal{C}}_2:=\mathcal{L}^2(\Omega,\mathcal{C},P_{\mathcal{C}}) / \mathcal{N}(\Omega,\mathcal{C},P_{\mathcal{C}})$$

with the same notation as before. Then both $L_2$ and $L^{\mathcal{C}}_2$ are Hilbert spaces with the usual inner product.

Since $\mathcal{L}^2(\Omega,\mathcal{C},P_{\mathcal{C}}) \subset \mathcal{L}^2(\Omega,\mathcal{A},P)$ and $\mathcal{N}(\Omega,\mathcal{C},P_{\mathcal{C}}) \subset  \mathcal{N}(\Omega,\mathcal{A},P)$, we see that each equivalent class of $L^{\mathcal{C}}_2$ is included in some equivalent class of $L^2$. Moreover, if $X,Y\in \mathcal{L}^2(\Omega,\mathcal{C},P_{\mathcal{C}})$ belong to the same equivalent class in $L^2$, then $X=Y$ $P$-a.s. (hence also $P_{\mathcal{C}}$-a.s.), and so $X$ and $Y$ are from the same equivalent class in $L^{\mathcal{C}}_2$.

The previous argument shows that there exist an linear injection $I:L^2_{\mathcal{C}}\to L^2$. Because only null sets are involved, we see that

$$||\tilde{X}||_{L^{\mathcal{C}}_2}=||I(\tilde{X})||_{L_2} \hspace{1cm} \text{and} \hspace{1cm} \langle \tilde{X},\tilde{Y} \rangle_{L^{\mathcal{C}}_2}= \langle I(\tilde{X}),I(\tilde{Y}) \rangle_{L^{}_2}$$

for all $\tilde{X},\tilde{Y} \in L^{\mathcal{C}}_2$. Hence from the completeness of $L^2_{\mathcal{C}}$ follows the completeness of $I(L^{\mathcal{C}}_2)$, i.e. $I(L^{\mathcal{C}}_2)$ is a Hilbert subspace of $L^2$.

Now the argument can proceed as before with the conclusions unchanged. For example the projection theorem now reads

For every $\tilde{X} \in L^2$ and there is a unique vector $\tilde{X}_0 \in I(L^{\mathcal{C}}_2)$ such that

$$ || \tilde{X} - \tilde{X}_0 ||_{L^2} =\min_{\tilde{Y} \in I(L^{\mathcal{C}}_2)} || \tilde{X} - \tilde{Y} ||_{L^2} $$

which, on account of the injectivity of $I$, is translated as

For every $\tilde{X} \in L^2$ and there is a unique vector $\tilde{X}_0 \in L^{\mathcal{C}}_2$ such that

$$ || \tilde{X} - \tilde{X}_0 ||_{L^2} =\min_{\tilde{Y} \in L^{\mathcal{C}}_2} || \tilde{X} - \tilde{Y} ||_{L^2} $$

Comment: Looks right. ${}{}$